# What is the proper way of registering new user using IdentityServer4 with multiple clients?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am building 2 MVC applications and will be using IdentityServer as a single sign-on authentication provider.  By following the sample code from IdentityServer web site, I can get the authentication working.  But now I am confused about how to register new users in the MVC applications.

For example in MVC 1, I have a secured controller action. Now accessing this action will be redirected to IdentityServer login page.  If user selected an external login provider and login successfully, then the user will be redirected to the "Register" page of IdentityServer to ask whether the user wants to register. If user clicks "Register", then redirected to the secured action successfully.  So far the sample code has done all these.  But my question is that MVC1 & MVC2 need some more information about the user for registration.  How can I prompt user to input these additional information?  It is not feasible to have these information inputted in the IdentityServer register page because MVC 1 & 2 need different information.  But if I have a register page in MVC1 & MVC2, then how can I force user to complete the registration?  After user is authenticated from IdentityServer, he is returned directly to the originally requested Url.  I just can't have code in every controller action to verify whether an authenticated user have completed the detailed registration.

An ideal way is that once a user is authenticated from IdentityServer, I can check whether this user has been registered in the local MVC user database.  If not, then redirect the user to the local MVC register page and then back to the originally requested Url.  How this can be done or is there a more appropriate way for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But my question is that MVC1 & MVC2 need some more information about
>   the user for registration.

To retrieve additional user info, you could depend on **user claims** for the additional user information. Otherwise, there is an endpoint called [UserInfo Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html)

> But if I have a register page in MVC1 & MVC2, then how can I force
>   user to complete the registration?

Based on client_id you could change the registration view

> I just can't have code in every controller action to verify whether an
>   authenticated user have completed the detailed registration.

You could create a customize filter to validate that. But, I would say try to keep the user related details on IdS4 project

> I can check whether this user has been registered in the local MVC
>   user database. If not, then redirect the user to the local MVC
>   register page and then back to the originally requested Url. How this
>   can be done or is there a more appropriate way for doing this?

If you think, these user information will **only be used for this client** then you could take this approach.

However, if possible you asked for all the required details on the user registration page, no harms keeping the information for mvc1 users. But sometimes it is not possible (e.g. internal vs external users). If it is for internal users, then I guess it would be better to have a seperate Admin UI where user can add extra information.

Anyway, if you want to keep everything in one user registration page on Id server, i would add an extra flag on Client table which will indicate to show extra fileds. Hope this may help you.